# If you change the default theme in VS Code, the terminal theme does not change. How do you want me to solve this problem?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, themes

I understand that when you change the default theme in VS Code, the theme is changed in the original terminal as well.

By the way, I used the https://glitchbone.github.io/vscode-base16-term/ #/monokai site to set the terminal theme differently before.

I also installed an extension program and used it.

But now, setting.json also deleted the settings and the extension program, but only the terminal theme has not changed when the default theme is changed.

As I did before, if you specify another terminal color directly using setting.json, it will change.

How do I fix that when I change the default theme, the terminal theme doesn't change?

Uninstalled VS code extension base 16 terminal and also removed the appropriate settings from setting.json.

If you change the theme in VS code, I want the terminal to change according to the theme.

Comment: screenshots of before and after please?